# How to change the DataTable scrollbar appearance?

Tags: primefaces

I tried to find with FireBug the proper CSS class responsible for the **DataTable** scrollbar appearance, but I couldn't find any reasonable css class. The table scrollbar is browser dependent - looks different in every browser. So how can I implement one scrollbar appearance for every browser?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by CSS, using WebKit. Actually PrimeFaces has some modifications done to the normal scrollbar in there CSS.

The scrollbar webkit are:

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar              { /* 1 */ }
::-webkit-scrollbar-button       { /* 2 */ }
::-webkit-scrollbar-track        { /* 3 */ }
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece  { /* 4 */ }
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb        { /* 5 */ }
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner       { /* 6 */ }
::-webkit-resizer                { /* 7 */ }
```

Some of these are implemented by PrimeFaces, so sometimes `!important` is needed.

Here's a quick example based on [an article](http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/).

```css
 /* !important is needed sometimes */
 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px !important;
 }

 /* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3) !important; 
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px !important;
   border-radius: 10px !important;
 }

 /* Handle */
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px !important;
   border-radius: 10px !important;
   background: rgba(255,0,0,0.8) !important; 
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5) !important; 
 }
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
   background: rgba(255,0,0,0.4) !important; 
 }
```

*Here's the outcome:*

[image: scrollbar]

A small working example can be found on [github](https://github.com/hatemalimam/DailyLab/blob/master/src/main/webapp/datatable/main.xhtml) and an [online Demo](http://jsf.hatemalimam.com/DailyLab/datatable/main.xhtml).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This solution works perfect, but only in the Google Chrome, in FF and IE standard scrollbar is displayed. Do you know if there is any browser independent solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This just work for **IE**

`html {
scrollbar-base-color:#8C8CC6;
  scrollbar-3d-light-color:#FFFFFF;
  scrollbar-arrow-color:#FFFFFF;
  scrollbar-darkshadow-color:#000000;
  scrollbar-face-color:#8C8CC6;
  scrollbar-highlight-color:#FFFFFF;
  scrollbar-shadow-color:#000000;
  scrollbar-track-color:#ACACE6;
}`